# Is it possible to scale a control in a VisualState

Tags: xaml, windows-10-universal

Using MinWindowWidth in an AdaptiveTrigger I am able change the background color but I am unable to apply a scale transform.

```
<VisualState x:Name="NarrowState">
    <VisualState.StateTriggers>
        <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="0"
    </VisualState.StateTriggers>
    <VisualState.Setters>
        <Setter Target="hsCards.(Control.Background)">
            <Setter.Value>
                 <SolidColorBrush Color="Green"/>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Target="hubFlashCards.(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.ScaleX)" Value="0.8"/>
            <Setter Target="hubFlashCards.(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.ScaleY)" Value="0.8"/>
    </VisualState.Setters>
</VisualState>
```

Not only does the scaling not work but the background Setter does not either. If I remove the scale transform the background Setter works fine.
Am I doing something wrong or is it not possible to use the RenderTransform in this way?

Comment: Sorry the code did not display due to a formatting issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case I would assign `x:Name` straight to the `CompositeTrasform` element. And then the Visual state:

```
 <VisualState x:Name="NarrowState">
    <VisualState.StateTriggers>
        <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="0">
    </VisualState.StateTriggers>
    <VisualState.Setters>
        <Setter Target="hsCards.Background">
            <Setter.Value>
                 <SolidColorBrush Color="Green"/>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Target="yourComposite1.ScaleX" Value="0.8"/>
            <Setter Target="yourComposite1.ScaleY" Value="0.8"/>
    </VisualState.Setters>
</VisualState>
```

I may not be exactly like your solution, but it's the way I use since I started with UWP.

Comment: Thanks Filippo B. Just to clarify I have edited your answer to show how to declare the RenderTransform.

Comment: where did you declare it? I don't see it and I can't get this solution to work